# Gitlab LDAP login with multiple domain user search

Tags: ldap, gitlab, kolab

I run a Kolab service on a separate VM from GitLab and have set multiple domains there.
I cannot configure GitLab to search the login user in several (all) domains on the same Kolab Groupware server, i.e. ou=People,dc=mydomain1,dc=com and ou=People,dc=mydomain2,dc=com. 
I have tried with setting only 'ou=People', putting wildcards, using LDAP search operator (|(ou=...,dc=..)(ou...)) and many other things, but without luck.
This is the current configuration that works with one domain (which is also the main, parent domain of the Kolab configuration):

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-'EOS' # remember to close this block with 'EOS' below
  main: # 'main' is the GitLab 'provider ID' of this LDAP server
    label: 'LDAP'
    host: 'my.host.com'
    port: 389
    uid: 'mail'
    method: 'plain' # "tls" or "ssl" or "plain"
    bind_dn: 'uid=kolab-service,ou=Special Users,dc=mydomain1,dc=com'
    password: 'mypassword'
    active_directory: false
    allow_username_or_email_login: false
    block_auto_created_users: false
    base: 'ou=People,dc=mydomain1,dc=com'
    user_filter: ''
```

Is there any way to set the 'base' parameter so I could login with users from multiple domains (but on the same LDAP server)?